# Vue test utils: mock getter return value

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm writing a test that mocks the return value of a namespaced getter, which accepts a single argument. The test parameter will be the mocked return value for the getter, which controls the visibility of an element on the page.

Mocking the getter with a generic return value allows it to be defined, but so far mocking the return value with the test parameter is not working.

Getter (in the "app" module):

```js
const getters = {
  myGetter:
    (state) =>
    (getterArg) => {
      return state.someStateVariable === true
        ? valueForTrue
        : valueForFalse;
    }
};
```

Test:

```js
import { cloneDeep }  from "lodash";
import { createLocalVue, shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import MyComponent from "@/views/MyComponent.vue";
import { storeConfig } from "@/store";
import Vuex from "vuex";
   
describe("My test", () => {
  let localVue;
  let store;
  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    localVue = createLocalVue();
    localVue.use(Vuex);
  });

  test.each([[false], [true]])(
    "Test param: '%s'",
    (testParam) => {
      store = new Vuex.Store({
        modules: {
          app: {
            namespaced: true,
            ...cloneDeep(storeConfig.modules.app),
            state: {
              ...cloneDeep(storeConfig.modules.app.state),
            getters: {
              ...cloneDeep(storeConfig.modules.app.getters),
              // getter defined, but doesn't include test param
              myGetter: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(jest.fn())

              // getter variation with a mocked return value (test fails due to testParam not being returned)
              myGetter: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(jest.fn().mockReturnValue(testParam))

              // getter variation with the argument passed by the component, and a mocked return value (test fails due to testParam not being returned)
              myGetter: jest.fn("getterArg").mockReturnValue(jest.fn().mockReturnValue(testParam))
            }
          }
        }
      });

      wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, {
        localVue,
        store
      });

      expect(wrapper.find("#my-element").exists()).toBe(
        testParam
      );
```

I also tried updating the wrapper after creation:

```js
  // Test fails due to getter being undefined
  Object.defineProperty(wrapper.vm, "app/myGetter", {
    value: () => {
      return testParam;
    }
  });

  // Test fails due to getter being undefined
  Object.defineProperty(wrapper.vm, "app/myGetter", {
    value: ("getterArg") => {
      return testParam;
    }
  });
```

How can this namespaced getter be configured to dynamically return the test parameter?

Comment: The question doesn't contain the original code. It's unknown how the test needs to be fixed in order to pass

Comment: This may sound silly, but did you try `jest.fn().mockReturnValue(testParam)`  or  `jest.fn().mockReturnValue([testParam])` (testParam wrapped in [])

Comment: EstusFlask I added the code for the getter. @Zarko I tried your suggestions, but they result in the getter being undefined: "TypeError: myGetter is not a function". Out of curiosity, why would the square brackets be necessary?

Comment: @GrowthMindset Actually brackets are not. I had issues with brackets before but I was misled in this case. Ok, not sure why it doesn't work, but you can mock the state instead of the getter, and then validate that the getter returns what is expected and respectively what is applied to the element in question.

Comment: @Zarko Mocking the state would normally be a solution. In this case the app uses an instance of a third party SDK to get a value from a service, and the getter that I'm trying to mock returns true/false based upon the result from the SDK.

The SDK instance methods are mocked with jest.fn(). I will try mock the return for the method being used in this test scenario as an alternative approach.